# Unexpected end of file (#2034) in MVC/ASP .NET C# solution

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I'm calling a stored procedure and the result is in ISingleResult<>...I created an xml document and then try to load the xml. I get an error on this line:

```
xml.LoadXml(airport.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B);
```

The error says: `{"Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1, position 2034."}`

This is the XML it's returning ends like this:

```
<EndTm>2215</EndTm> \n\t<D"`
```

If I call the SP with the itineraryId and ItineraryItemId I get:

```
<AirSegSellMods ItineraryItemID="1">
  ...
</AirSegSellMods>
```

It's as if visual studio is getting a truncated version of the XML.

```
foreach(ItineraryItems item in ItineraryItems) {
     if (item.SuperCategoryId == 4) {

        StoredProceduresDataContext airProc2 = new StoredProceduresDataContext();

        ISingleResult < STOREDPROC> airportsFromSalesId = airProc2.STOREDPROC(item.ItineraryId, item.ItineraryItemId);

        List < AirItinerary > listOfAir = new List < AirItinerary > ();
        foreach(STOREDPROC airport in airportsFromSalesId) {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(airport.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B);

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/AirSegSellMods/AirSegSell"); 
            foreach(XmlElement xn in xnList) {

                listOfAir.Add(new AirItinerary() {
                    FltNum = xn.GetAttribute("FltNum"),
                    StartDt = xn.GetAttribute("StartDt"),
                    //...continued
                });
            }
        }
        item.AirItems = listOfAir;
    }
}
```

I have done something very similar to this before with no such problems. My coworker runs the exact same code and doesn't get this error so I think it's something specific to a visual studio setting.

Any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing xml.LoadXml(airport.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B);

to xml.Load(airport.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B);

assuming that path is correct it should work.

Comment: If I change it I get this exception: {"Illegal characters in path."}